# Setting a prompt to UINavigation Bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I tried to search but I can't find the right answer for me.
I tried to set a PromptText in the navigationBar but it does not work.
No matter where i put this line of Code

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.prompt = @"MyTitle";
```

It does not work. I put it in the Child and RootViewController. The effect is that the RootView Controller has a prompt but not the ChildViewController.
Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to do exactly. But you shouldn't just change the `topItem`. Instead, change the view controller's navigation item like this:

```
self.navigationItem.prompt = @"MyTitle";
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sometimes the answer is sooo easy ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on when it is called, it might not have the effect you expect because it depends on what topItem is at that time.  Instead, set the prompt from each view controller's `navigationItem.prompt`.

Comment: Indeed, it seems the prompt can not be changed from the UINavigationController class (in ViewDidLoad), and needs to be set from one of the subviews. It's more like "a prompt for the current view" than a global prompt for all the views handled by the navigation controller.